# New collection not showing after successful import using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, openshift

Any idea why `collection` not showing in results? I've set `lastmanstanding` as current `db`

```
[host repo]\> mongoimport --db $OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME --collection players --drop --host $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_HOST --port $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PORT --username $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_USERNAME  --password $OPENSHIFT_MONGODB_DB_PASSWORD --file db/primer-dataset-players.json --jsonArray
connected to: 127.2.202.130:27017
Sun Oct 18 11:15:19.789 dropping: MyDatabaseName.players
Sun Oct 18 11:15:19.796 imported 3 objects
[lastmanstanding-bobbyrne01.rhcloud.com repo]\> mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: 127.2.202.130:27017/admin
Welcome to the MongoDB shell.
For interactive help, type "help".
For more comprehensive documentation, see
    http://docs.mongodb.org/
Questions? Try the support group
    http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user
> set MyDatabaseName
set MyDatabaseName to true
> show collections
system.indexes
system.users
```

Contents of `db/primer-dataset-players.json` ..

```
[
    {
        "name": "bobbyrne01",
        "id": 21
    },
    {
        "name": "Someone",
        "id": 55
    }
]
```

Comment: You likely want `use MyDatabaseName` instead of `set MyDatabaseName`

Comment: @JohnnyHK that worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command to set the current database is `use` not `set`. See [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/) for docs.

So it should be:

```
> use MyDatabaseName
```

instead of

```
> set MyDatabaseName
```